# No "Store" menu available in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have downloaded the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 from MS site. I have installed it in two ways :

1. WPexpress_full installed via web.
2. wpsdkv80_enu1.iso (1.6 Gb) download and install.

In both the cases, I could not find the store menu. I have developed an app and it has to be submitted to the Windows Phone Store. I could not find any solutions over these forums. I need some guidance.

Note: I also tried to find this menu by looking in Tools - > customize options. That did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit Windows Phone 8 apps using just Visual Studio. You have to login here and submit the XAP with your app using the New App dialog:
[Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually begin the app submission process with the store from Visual Studio 2012 via the menu with:  Project >>> Store >>> Reserve App Name...

However, this is just a link to the actual website:  https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Developer/Catalog/ReleaseAnchor